# Eclipse debugging Android app - debugger shows wrong line executing

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, dalvik

While implementing Twitter integration in my app, I discovered the following oddness of the Eclipse debugger.  What is causing this?

I'm using this AsyncTask for getting a request token from twitter using twitter4j 3.0.3.

```
    public class TwitterRequestAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, RequestToken> {

        private Context context;

        public TwitterRequestAsync(Context context) {

            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected RequestToken doInBackground( Void... params ) {

            Twitter twitter = getTwitter();     // getTwitter() is in enclosing class
            try {
                RequestToken token = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
                return token;
            }
            catch (TwitterException e) {
                Log.e( TAG, e.getMessage(), e );
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( RequestToken result ) {

            super.onPostExecute( result );
            if ( result != null ) {
                // stuffs concerning request token here
            }
        }

    }
```

When I debug this code it appears that there is an exception thrown when getOAuthRequestToken() executes and the next line that the debugger shows executing is in the catch clause, return null;

However, the result that is returned to onPostExecute(...) is a valid request token, so the debugger is doing something weird.  I've cleaned my project and restarted Eclipse each multiple times with no change in this behavior.  Am I broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue.  It appears that it could be a problem with the Dalvik VM.  The last return statement of the method is shown to execute in the debugger.

Changing the doInBackground body to:

```
        @Override
        protected RequestToken doInBackground( Void... params ) {

            Twitter twitter = getTwitter();
            RequestToken token = null;
            try {
                token = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
            }
            catch (TwitterException e) {
                Log.e( TAG, e.getMessage(), e );
            }
            return token;
        }
```

Causes execution to appear to proceed as expected.

See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/DEU6JmdyFyM for an old mention of the problem with a link to an even older mention.  Someone finally created an issue for this at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34193.

Answer (score 1):

As your self-answer notes, this is a known issue.  I wanted to point out that it (and other quirks) are documented in the Dalvik docs.  You can find it in the [official but raw](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/master/docs/debugger.html) form, or [unofficial but formatted](http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/debugger.html) -- skip down to "Known Issues and Limitations".

It would be nice if the documentation was more prominent.

Comment: Thanks for linking the Dalvik docs! I didn't come across that in my searches.  In fact, I came across very little regarding this behavior in my searching which is the main reason I posted it here.

Comment: The "dx" converter introduces some oddities, but does actually go out of its way to generate code that is inferior for performance but superior for debugging if it thinks you might attach a debugger later.  See e.g. my post on https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/5HSRZEdPtCk .  IIRC, the return-combining stuff was harder to unravel.