# switch statement is not working ("jumping around" weirdly)

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I use some really simple switch...But it does not work. I just don't see any mistake in my switch...

I added 3 comments to my code to show, which points are reached or not reached if I enter with `type == BODYSIZE`...

I don't see how it can happen, that "1)" is reached and "2)" not... but debugging exactly shows me this... It just jumps to "3)" after it was at "1)"...

I tried deleting the app from my phone, deleting the bin/gen folder and rebuilding the project, but apperently the problem really is in the code... I just don't see it...

```
public static void getMinMaxValuesForNumberPicker(LengthType type, IntegerHolder min1, IntegerHolder max1, IntegerHolder min2, IntegerHolder max2)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case BODYSIZE: // cm bzw. ft + in
        {
            // 0 - 3m (3m ~ 9.84ft)
            if (getCurrentLengthUnit() == LengthUnit.METER)
            {
                min1.set(0);
                max1.set(300);
            }
            else
            {
                min1.set(0);
                max1.set(10);
                min2.set(0);
                max2.set(11);              // <= 1) IS REACHED
            }
            return;                     // <= 2) IS NOT REACHED
        }
        case CIRCUMFERENCE: // cm bzw. in
        { // 0 - 500cm (500cm ~ 196.85in)
            if (getCurrentLengthUnit() == LengthUnit.METER)
            {
                min1.set(0);
                max1.set(500);
            }
            else
            {
                min1.set(0);
                max1.set(200);
            }
            return;
        }
        case WRINKLE: // cm bzw. in
        { // 0 - 50cm (50cm ~ 19.69in)
            if (getCurrentLengthUnit() == LengthUnit.METER)
            {
                min1.set(0);
                max1.set(50);
            }
            else
            {
                min1.set(0);
                max1.set(20);
            }
            return;
        }
        case DISTANCE: // km + m bzw. mi + yd
        { // 0 - 1000km (1000km ~ 621.37mi)
            if (getCurrentLengthUnit() == LengthUnit.METER)
            {
                min1.set(0);
                max1.set(1000);
                min2.set(0);
                max2.set(999);
            }
            else
            {
                min1.set(0);
                max1.set(500);
                min2.set(0);
                max2.set(1759);
            }
            return;                       // <= 3) IS REACHED
        }
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("getMinMaxValuesForNumberPicker für " + type.name() + " nicht implementiert!");
    }
}
```

Comment: replace `return` with `break`

Comment: Could it be that your compiler optimizes this to only one return statement and use breaks everywhere else? In the end, that is functionally the same. Besides, don't always trust the debugger. You could add log statements just before each return and check which are executed.

Comment: It really seems to be that way... Debugging statements emphase this theory... Adding debugging statements before 2) and 3) result in only printing the one before 2)... Actually, just like the debugging session makes one assume... does that mean, that I don't have to worry about this behaviour? It still seams to be somehow strange..

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604674/eclipse-debugging-android-app-debugger-shows-wrong-line-executing) which describes a similar phenomenon.

Comment: actually, your link shows that this is a normal behaviour and represents a know issue... so thanks, this would be the answer to my question what is going on here

Answer (score 2):

```
switch (key)
     {
        case value :{
           //do something...
        }
           break;

        default :
           break;
     }
```

My assumption is that the return does not rly ends the switch - but Im not sure about this.

Comment: actually, I normally don't write brackets there anyway, only if I define variables in the cases... I just added the brackets for test purposes and without them, I get exactly the same behaviour...

Comment: So using `break` instead of `return` also does not help?

Comment: i will try... but I used returns already at least a thousand times and it always worked... the return should always end the switch (as it will result in leaving the current function)... but I'll test it...

Comment: Im also a bit confused by the jump from step 1 to 3. A bit spooky, indeed. Lets see if the breaks instead of returns helped, but at my little example I just tested it didn't change anything...

Comment: I tried it with brakes... the weird thing is, I can't say if this helps... I dont reach 3) but the debugger does not stop at the break statement...

Comment: it seems to work correctly both ways, but I never had such a weird behaviour before... And would really like to know why this is happening...

Comment: Hm, too bad.. Seems like (atleast I) can't help you any further then.. Inform us if you found it out by yourself... Und viel Erfolg dabei :)

Comment: it really seems to be like Heuster wrote... An compiler optimisation... everything seems to work correctly, just the debugging feedback is misleading... Und danke schön :-)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there's nothing wrong with your code, it's working fine. I guess you're using eclipse, then when you're debugging with Android it always goes to the last return line in the method, it just reach there but not execute that line (this should be a bug of eclipse). 
I added some logs into your code like this:

```
public static void getMinMaxValuesForNumberPicker() {
        Log.i("TestActivity", "Your method *******************");

        int type = 0;
        int min1 = 0, min2 = 0, max1 = 0, max2 = 0;

        switch (type) {
        case 0: // cm bzw. ft + in
        {
            // 0 - 3m (3m ~ 9.84ft)
            if (min1 > min2) {
                min1 = 0;
                max1 = 300;
            } else {
                min1 = 0;
                max1 = 10;
                min2 = 0;
                max2 = 11; // <= 1) IS REACHED
                Log.i("TestActivity", " 1) IS REACHED");
            }
            Log.i("TestActivity", " 2) IS REACHED");
            return; // <= 2) IS NOT REACHED
        }
        case 1: // cm bzw. in
        { // 0 - 500cm (500cm ~ 196.85in)
            if (min1 == 1) {
                min1 = 0;
                max1 = 500;
            } else {
                min1 = 0;
                max1 = 200;
            }
            return;
        }
        case 2: // cm bzw. in
        { // 0 - 50cm (50cm ~ 19.69in)
            if (min1 < min2) {
                min1 = 0;
                max1 = 50;
            } else {
                min1 = 0;
                max1 = 20;
            }
            return;
        }
        case 3: // km + m bzw. mi + yd
        { // 0 - 1000km (1000km ~ 621.37mi)
            if (min1 < min2) {
                min1 = 0;
                max1 = 1000;
                min2 = 0;
                max2 = 999;
            } else {
                min1 = 0;
                max1 = 500;
                min2 = 0;
                max2 = 1759;
            }
            Log.i("TestActivity", " 3) IS REACHED");
            return; // <= 3) IS REACHED
        }
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("getMinMaxValuesForNumberPicker für "
                    + type + " nicht implementiert!");
        }
    }
```

And the logs make things clear:

```
12-05 01:35:24.808: I/TestActivity(3784): Your method *******************
12-05 01:35:24.808: I/TestActivity(3784):  1) IS REACHED
12-05 01:35:24.808: I/TestActivity(3784):  2) IS REACHED
```

And, two more testing methods to make it more clear, you can try debugging them, it always reaches the last return line in the method

```
public static void testDebugingLine(int number) {
        Log.i("TestActivity", "Another example *******************");
        if (number < 0) {
            Log.e("TestActivity", "1 is reached");
            return;
        }

        Log.e("TestActivity", "2 is reached");
        return;
    }

    public static boolean testDebugingLine1(int number) {
        Log.i("TestActivity", "And another example *******************");
        if (number < 0) {
            Log.e("TestActivity", "1 is reached and return true");
            return true;
        }

        Log.e("TestActivity", "2 is reached and return false");
        return false;
    }
```

```
 testDebugingLine(-1);
 boolean result = testDebugingLine1(-1);
 Log.e("TestActivity", "testDebugingLine1() return " + result);
```

Logs:

```
12-05 01:35:24.808: I/TestActivity(3784): Another example *******************
12-05 01:35:27.861: E/TestActivity(3784): 1 is reached
12-05 01:35:32.326: I/TestActivity(3784): And another example *******************
12-05 01:35:34.368: E/TestActivity(3784): 1 is reached and return true
12-05 01:35:42.497: E/TestActivity(3784): testDebugingLine1() return true
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is outside of your code snipplet. Besides i don't really know what you're trying to achieve with this code. It does absolutely nothing besides wasting time and calling `getCurrentLengthUnit()` if you are in one of the cases and throw an exception otherwise. All assignments write to LOCAL variables and do not have effects on any other variables.

Your code has the same effect as the following implementation:

```
public static void getMinMaxValuesForNumberPicker(LengthType type, Integer min1, Integer max1, Integer min2, Integer max2)
{

    switch (type)
    {
        case BODYSIZE:
        case CIRCUMFERENCE:
        case WRINKLE:
        case DISTANCE:
            getCurrentLengthUnit();
            break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("getMinMaxValuesForNumberPicker für " + type.name() + " nicht implementiert!");
    }
}
```

So either you call `getMinMaxValuesForNumberPicker` from `getCurrentLengthUnit` or you expect that your assignments have effect on the variables that are not local to your function.
Writing to the parameters doesn't make the changes visible to the calling function:

```
Integer a=-1;
Integer b=-1;
Integer c=-1;
Integer d=-1;
getMinMaxValuesForNumberPicker(LengthType.BODYSIZE , a, b, c, d);
// a, b, c, d are still -1 here although you never assigned -1 and "assigned" null to the parameters in getMinMaxValuesForNumberPicker
// The parameters are just copies of the adresses of a, b, c and d and not aliases of a, b, c, and d
```

(I guess you didn't use the debugger to go through the code step by step. This may have caused some confusion.)

### Note: Question has been edited since the code has been posted

Comment: this does not have to do anything with the problem... I use a custom class with an internal int variable anyway now... didn't think of this at first... nevertheless, your statement is correct, but it does not have to do anything with the problem... Even if my code relating to integer would do nothing, that does not explain the weird behaviour.... PS: I do debug step by step, otherwise I could not have been able to add my comments 1) 2) 3)

Comment: PS: I change the Integer to IntHolder... so that this confusing point is removed...

Comment: Add a breakpoint to the line `switch(type)`, I'm sure you visit this breakpoint before visiting 3).

Comment: of cource I do... but what for? anyway, other answers explained everything already...

Comment: @prom85 Sorry, didn't see that answer before posting the comment.